# javascript : trying to get a synchronous behaviour with async/await and IIFE

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, iife

in the code below, I want to get msg#1, msg#2, msg#3 in this order.   I'm getting right now: msg#1, msg#3, msg#2.  thanks for help  ! Denys

```
function timeoutPromise(time) { return new Promise(function (resolve) { setTimeout(function () { resolve(Date.now()); }, time) }) }
function wait(howlong) { return timeoutPromise(howlong * 1000); }
async function doAsync() {
  var start = Date.now(), time;
  time = await wait(1); console.log('... ' + (time-start)/1000 );
  time = await wait(1); console.log('... ' + (time-start)/1000 );
}
console.log('msg#1');
(async () => { await doAsync(); console.log('msg#2'); })();
console.log('msg#3');
```

Answer (score 0):

`async` functions are asynchronous!

The function on the penultimate line is going to reach `await doAsync();`, go to sleep, and the parent function will continue with the next line `console.log('msg#3');`.

If you want to wait for that async function to finish, you need to `await` it too.

Comment: thanks Quentin, isn't it what I'm trying to do with the IIFE : (async () => { await doAsync(); console.log('msg#2'); })(); ?

Comment: You have an `await` **inside** the IIFE, but not outside it.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance with JS async/await, do you mind providing the exact line that would do the job ? thank you so much.

Comment: so is there finally a simple and practical way to answer this question ?

Answer (score 0):

an answer that I will suggest myself, more a workaround than a true answer..
let's hope we get an even better answer from the community.

```
(async () => { await doAsync(); console.log('msg#2'); everythingThatFollowsdoAsync(); })();

    function everythingThatFollowsdoAsync(){
        // let's do here the rest of the code, now that doAsync() is over. 
        console.log('msg#3');   
 }
```

and then I'm getting the expected output:

msg#1
1.002
2.003
msg#2
msg#3